# Bootstrap tabs unwanted switching

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use Bootstrap tabs and I've encountered a bit of a problem

**This works as expected and I can switch between tabs**

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
           <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link active" id="tabA-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabA">Tab A</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" id="tabB-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabB">Tab B</a>
           </li>
         </ul>
         <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
           <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tabA" role='tabpanel'>...</div>
           <div class="tab-pane fade" id="studio" role='tabB'>...</div>
         </div>
```

**When I add an onclick handler the tab switches but then immediately switches back to the first one.**

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
           <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link active" id="tabA-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabA" onclick='getTab()'>Tab A</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" id="tabB-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tabB">Tab B</a>
           </li>
         </ul>
         <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
           <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tabA" role='tabpanel'>...</div>
           <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tabB" role='tabpanel'>...</div>
         </div>
```

**Javascript for getTab()**

```
     function getTab()                                                                           
      {                                                                                               
         $.post ( "APIaddress" , function ( data ) {                                              
            $ ( "#tabA" ).html ( data );                                                                         
         } );                                                                                        
      }
```

What I've tried

- Moved the onclick to the li instead of the anchor
- Added event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropogation() to getTab()

Both have the same result

Additionally, if I remove the javascript onclick call completely (as in the first code snippet) the tab switches work properly.  If I then call the Javascript from the console it switches back to the first tab immediately